# Adding powers. Completely stumped on this

Tags: python

Can anyone show me how I can do this? Thanks.

The program needs to define a function sumPower, which should accept a list of numbers. Function sumPower should then use each item in the list as an exponent on the number 2. This function should add these powers and return the sum. You should also make sure to write a main program with a statement like:

print(  sumPower([2,4,6]) )

Comment: It's okay to ask questions about homework here, but you should try to show what you've tried, and where exactly you're stumped.

Answer (score 3):

Here you use *list comprehension*.
That means: take my list and for each element of that list calculate new value. Return the list of new elements.

For example:

```
In [2]: a=[2,4,6]

In [3]: print [pow(2,x) for x in a]
[4, 16, 64]
```

After that you need to calculate the sum of the elements in the list.
There is a function in Python that can sum all the elements in the list that is its argument.

```
In [4]: sum([2,4,6])
Out[4]: 12
```

Now you combine list comprehension and `sum`.

```
(try to guess)
```

When you are not allowed such constructs, you can write the same more low-level:

```
def sumPower(a):
  s = 0
  for x in a:
    s += pow(2,x)
  # (one line removed; try to guess what must be here)
```

Here you iterate through `a`, calculate the power of 2 and accumuluate it in the `s` variable. Then return `s` as a result of the function.

I modified the solution a little bit; I've hidden some code; just try to guess it yourself. It's very easy and when you guess it right, it would be more useful for you!

Comment: Since this is, in all likelyhood, homework, how about removing the final answer? The rest of your walkthrough is helpful for a student.